# C# WPF GMap.NET Z Index

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, gmap.net

I'm building a C#-WPF application (.NET Framework 4.5).
The application is a single page window that contains a map.

For the map i'm using GMap.NET and the following XAML code:

```html
 <WindowsFormsHost Panel.ZIndex="1">
  <WindowsFormsHost.Child>
    <gmap:GMapControl x:Name="MapViewUi"/>
  </WindowsFormsHost.Child>
</WindowsFormsHost>
<ContentControl Panel.ZIndex="5" Content="{Binding TopBarView}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
```

The Other map attributes are irrelevant.

Over the map i want to set a content control that will sometimes hide part of the map and without changing the map size (for that i used the ZIndex).

The issue is that no matter what ZIndex number i set for both map and content control, the map will be always on top.

How can i set the content control to be on top of the map?

Comment: Do you change zindex in runtime? If so do you force a redraw?

Comment: @Emad No, i set the ZIndex at the xaml code